# MongoDb on Catalina stuck on start

Tags: database, mongodb, macos, macos-catalina

I followed a couple guides to install MongoDB on Catalina but currently I'm having trouble starting it up.  When I input mongod the routine seems to get stuck at: `I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>`

Any ideas how to fix this?